# Intellij 2023 New UI Back Arrow icon

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea

In intellij 2023 new UI Beta, is it not possible to use the back navigation arrow icon that existed in the toolbar before?

Comment: Do you mean that icon is missing or nothing happens when you click on it?

Comment: @y.bedrov After changing to the beta ui, I don't see the navigate back/forward buttons that the toolbar had. Is there any way to add them?
I ask because I know there are shortcuts, but sometimes I find them useful in situations where they are not available

Comment: You may add them manually: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-296472/New-UI-Forward-and-Backward-Arrows#focus=Comments-27-6204786.0-0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Right Click the space of Toolbar.
   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayA5u.png)
2. Click "Customize Toolbar"
   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C84T5.png)
3. Click "Add Actions",then click "Add Action"
   [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ux4e.png)
4. Click "Main Menu" → "Navigate"→"Back" or "Forward",then click "OK"
   [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHAbu.png)
5. Hold and Drag “Back” or "Forward" to right position.
   [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfkzB.png)

Comment: It's better if you can add the images along the answer not as a number

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the positioning of the arrows on the left side of the toolbar, similar to the previous user interface:

1. Navigate to Settings
2. Under "Appearance & Behavior," choose "Menus and Toolbars."
3. In the right pane, select "Main toolbar left".
4. At the top, click on the "+" button and select "Add action."
5. Unfold the "Main Menu" section, then go to "Navigate."
6. Locate and select "Back," then confirm by clicking "Ok."
7. Apply the changes and restart your IDE.

Upon reboot, you will observe the newly added action within your toolbar.